# Not able to create query findByUserId(Long userId)

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Not able to create query findByUserId(Long userId)
I have tried
findByUserId(Long user_id)
findByuser_id(Long user_id)
findByUser_id(Long user_id)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JPA method, as currently named, expects a user ID variable name of `userId`, in camel case.  Use this definition:

```java
@Column(name="user_id")
private Long userId;
```

Then use `findByUserId(Long userId)` as the JPA repo method name as you were already doing.  Note that the `@Column` annotation directs JPA/Hibernate to create the table column with the name `user_id`.